# Keep reading input from next row in the same variable

Tags: sas

I have data from a chat that i want to read in one entry at the time. Every time a person has hit "send" should be one observation. The problem is when there is breaks (enter) in the text. I can't manage to make SAS keep reading this as the same observation. Here is some dummy data:

```
   08:23 - Greg: Hi!
   08:24 - Sue: Hello
   08:24 - Greg: How are you?
   08:25 - Sue: Just fine :)

   How are you then?
   08:26 - Greg: All good.
```

I want this to be 5 observations but i can only manage SAS to read this as 7 obs. Desired dataset should look like:

```
Obs   VAR1
1    08:23 - Greg: Hi!
2    08:24 - Sue: Hello
3    08:24 - Greg: How are you?
4    08:25 - Sue: Just fine :) How are you then?
5    08:26 - Greg: All good.
```

I play around with the code:

```
data testing;
infile datalines ;
input var1 $60. ;
datalines;
08:23 - Greg: Hi!
08:24 - Sue: Hello
08:24 - Greg: How are you?
08:25 - Sue: Just fine :)

How are you then?
08:26 - Greg: All good. 
;
```

But the actual file is a txt and have more irregularities than the above dummy example. I have tried to use the trailing @ but cant get it to work the way i want. Maybe trailing @ is not what i am after. Any suggestions how to proceed?

Comment: Do you need it to be perfectly formatted from the input or you can also post-process strings to gain the desired result?

Comment: Post-process is fine and it has been on my mind. Just get the feeling that i am missing something while i read in the data that might solve this easy.

Comment: Can you verify how the line breaks versus send is stored in your file?  Sometimes files like this use `'0A'x` (LF) for internal line breaks and `'0D0A'x` only after the send.

Comment: It seems that it is LF breaks only. Good thought thou, it could have made it much easier.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

Keep a running variable that is the last value.  If the current value has a time stamp in the first 4 characters, then output it and reset the value to "".  Append the current value to the running variable.  Finally, output the last line, no matter what.

```
data testing(keep=line);
set testing end=last;

format line $2000.;
retain line;

if _n_ > 1 then do;
    if index(substr(var1,1,4),":") then do;
        output;
        line = "";
    end;
end;

put line= var1=;
line = catx(" ",line , var1);
put line=;

if last then do;
    output;
    put "AT LAST";
end;
run;
```

Comment: what if there will be a chat like this:

15:00 - ME: this is a simple string, here a break the line[line break]
so: this punctuation will lead to a wrong line break
15:01 - YOU: you are right stat, my code doesn't work.

Comment: Your's fails with the same problem if someone hits enter and types something that looks like a time stamp.  You are not going to be able to code around that problem.

Comment: that's true, but please give a try with my code, 'so:' won't produce a wrong classification, but yes, if after hitting enter they write an hour with hhmm format obviously my code will have the same bad behaviour.

Comment: Are you able to insert your own tokens to identify where messages start/finish, or are you importing from a file that's already been provided to you?  Can the person who provided the file insert the tokens for you?  That would allow you to code around that issue.

Comment: I would read the first 5 characters using ??TIME5. informat and test if it is non null so values that have a colon but are not valid times would not trigger a new entry. You can also test if the 7th character is a hyphen.

Comment: Can't insert tokens in a good way in the file. However, in my actual file there is a date aswell (dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm) which i might have included in my dummy example. The date together with the timestamp should ensure that i only get valid entrys.

Answer (score 0):

I unsuccesfully tried to find a solution in row data input, anyway I hope that this will be useful for you, postprocessing strings:

```
data testing;
infile datalines ;
input var1 $60.;
datalines;
08:23 - Greg: Hi!
08:24 - Sue: Hello
08:24 - Greg: How are you?
08:25 - Sue: Just fine :)

How are you then?
08:26 - Greg: All good. 
;

data testing01;
set testing;
retain row 0;
if input(substr(var1,1,2),8.) le 24 and input(substr(var1,1,2),8.) ne .
and substr(var1,3,1)=':' 
and input(substr(var1,4,2),8.) le 59 and input(substr(var1,4,2),8.) ne . then row = row+1; else row=row;
run;

proc transpose data=testing01 out=testing02;
var var1;
by row;
run;

data testing03;
length final $2000;
set testing02;
array str[*] col:;
do i=1 to dim(str);
if str[i] ne '' then final=cats(strip(final)||' '||strip(str[i]));
end; 
drop col: row i _name_;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
filename FT15F001 temp;  
data testing ;
infile FT15F001 end=eof ;
length string $6323;
retain string;
input @;
if _n_=1 then string=_infile_;
else if not missing(_infile_) and anydigit(_infile_)^=1 then string=catx(' ',string,_infile_);
else if not missing(_infile_) and anydigit(_infile_)=1 then do;
   output;
   call missing(string);
   string=_infile_;
end;
if eof then output;
PARMCARDS;
08:23 - Greg: Hi!
08:24 - Sue: Hello
08:24 - Greg: How are you?
08:25 - Sue: Just fine :)

How are you then?
08:26 - Greg: All good. 
;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to do this, depending on your particular use case.

Here's a regular expression one. This won't work if you have > 32767 total characters, unless you have some way to split it into chunks, but for smaller files works well; and the general approach can be used even if you read in a line at a time.

```
data test;
infile "c:\temp\chat.txt" recfm=f lrecl=32767;
input @;
rx_find = prxparse('~(\d\d:\d\d -.*?)(?=(?:\b\d\d:\d\d)|$)~ios');
rc_find = prxmatch(rx_find,_infile_);
pos=1;
pos2=0;
start=1;
call prxposn(rx_find,1,pos,len);
do until (pos2=0);
    call prxposn(rx_find,1,pos,len);
    found=substr(_infile_,pos,len);
    output;
    start=pos+len;
    call prxnext(rx_find,start,-1,_infile_,pos2,len2);
end;
stop;
run;
```

Comment: Intersesting solution. These prx-functions are new to me. Seems like they could be useful. My file is quite large so i have to make some modification for this solution.